# Multiple Queries in Banana with Solr (like in Kibana and elasticsearch)

Tags: solr, kibana, banana

Is it possible to use multiple queries in LucidWorks Banana with Solr (like with Kibana and elasticsearch)? We would like to display them in one diagram/histogram using different colors...

The way we want it: Screenshot how it looks like in Kibana/ElasticSearch

[image]

What we already got: Banana with just one query per diagram/histogram

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are currently working on supporting it, You will find it in the next version 1.5

if you have any more questions you can contact us https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana/issues